# What does "%:" (percent colon) mean in C?

Tags: c, gcc

In one of my courses I've been given this cryptic c code.

```
%:define BBRACE (
%:define BRACEE )
%:define CCURLY_BRACE {
%:define CURLY_BRACEE }
%:define SEMICOLON ;
%:define COMMA ,
int main BBRACE int argc COMMA char *argv<::> BRACEE CCURLY_BRACE return 1^2^3^4^5^6^7 SEMICOLON CURLY_BRACEE
```

Its not that complicated but I've never seen `%:define ...` is there any difference to `#define ...`? I found nothing about `%:`online.

Same goes with `char *argv<::>` but I don't know if this really deserves a second question.

Comment: I think the macros are even worse than the digraphs. Blech!

Comment: In the spirit of the thing, it should be `%: define CCURLY_BRACE <%`

Comment: Or better yet, `??=define CCURLY_BRACE ??<`, and `return 1 ??' 2 ??' 3 ??' 4 ??' 5 ??' 6 ??' 7 SEMICOLON`